# Xamarin.Android - Localization

Tags: c#, android, localization, xamarin, xamarin.android

guys! How can I localize my application in Xamarin.Android? I have tried creating strings folder, but it works only when user change the language of OS. However, I need to launch my application in English as an default language, then user should be able to change application's language.

Comment: Why are you requiring someone to follow English instructions on changing to the device language, rather than defaulting to the language of the OS? Having your app change language when the OS language changes is the correct way to do localisation.

Comment: @DavidArno I know, but I want to give chance to user being able to personalize their profile. For example, in Facebook it shows default language for the first time, but if we want, we can change it easily. So, I want to do something like this.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android